# Having a xyz tileLayer just covering a certain region of the world

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to overlay the following xyz tile layer to a leaflet map.

`http://weatheroo.net/radar/data/2019/07/15/18/40/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

It is a weather radar composite of germany, this is the reason why it's just covers middle europe.

The bounding box:

```
new L.LatLng(45.530, 1.07006),
new L.LatLng(55.7750629, 17.095451751)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6jtr38e7/

The image appears but does not fit to the bounds.
Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue I can see is missing template arguments in your example options.

You url template string has 5 extra attributes: `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, and `minutes`. You need to include those in `TileLayer` options. It seems the tile server requires two-digit numbers for these attributes, so make sure you pass them in the correct format. Here's an example:

```
L.tileLayer('http://weatheroo.net/radar/data/{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}/{minute}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    detectRetina: false,
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 6,
    minNativeZoom: 1,
    maxNativeZoom: 6,
    zIndex: 830,
    className: 'tiles_radar',
    crossOrigin: false,
    year: "2019",
    month: "07",
    day: "14",
    hour: "18",
    minute: "40",
    bounds:[
        new L.LatLng(45.530, 1.07006),
        new L.LatLng(55.7750629, 17.095451751)
    ]
})
```

If you need dynamic values for the above attributes, you can use a function to get the needed values. Here's an example that uses the current date and time and formats the relevant ones with two digits to generate the tile url:

```
L.tileLayer('http://weatheroo.net/radar/data/{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}/{minute}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    detectRetina: false,
    minZoom: 1,
    maxZoom: 6,
    minNativeZoom: 1,
    maxNativeZoom: 6,
    zIndex: 830,
    className: 'tiles_radar',
    crossOrigin: false,
    year: () => (new Date()).getFullYear().toString(),
    month: () => `0${((new Date()).getMonth() + 1)}`.slice(-2),
    day: () => `0${((new Date()).getDate())}`.slice(-2),
    hour: `0${((new Date()).getHours())}`.slice(-2),
    minute: `0${((new Date()).getMinutes())}`.slice(-2),
    bounds:[
        new L.LatLng(45.530, 1.07006),
        new L.LatLng(55.7750629, 17.095451751)
    ]
})
```

One more thing: I noticed `weatheroo.net` does not support https, but jsfiddle redirects all the tile urls to https. So even after updating the options, the example is not going to work in jsfiddle. Try it locally or with another service.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am having a leaflet TimeDimension plugin running with this kind of data. I overlayed the whole image to the map but i guess it is not the fastest way to load data to the map so I decided to seperate the image in tiles. So acessing the image is not the problem. (the locally running applicatiion has no problem, I just want to make it easier for you to help me) The issue is to bound the layer to the bounding coordinates. So that all of tiles are displayed between this coordinates.

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5818 this issue tells you that it is not working as i want it.